# Enriching a ggplot2 plot with multiple geom_segment in a loop?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I successfully create a plot using the following:

```
# suppose I have a p <- ggplot(data=df, ...) then the following works 
# I get those two segments plotted correctly
p <- p + geom_segment(aes(x=1,y=103,xend=1,yend=107))
p <- p + geom_segment(aes(x=5,y=103,xend=5,yend=107))
```

However if I do:

```
values <- c(1, 5)
for (i in values) {
   p <- p + geom_segment(aes(x=i,y=103,xend=i,yend=107))
}
```

It doesn't work, only the last segment is created. Can anyone advice what's wrong here?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It has to do with the lazy evaluation of the `aes()` values. You are binding to the variable `i` but not actually doing anything with it in the loop. The mappings aren't resolved till you actually `print(p)`. Essentially this means they are all being bound to `i` and after the loop exits, `i` will have the value it had during the final loop.

So the problem really is you shounld't be using `aes()` here as you don't really want active binding. Just set the `x` and `xend` values outside the `aes()`. (And since the `y`'s are constant they should be outside the `aes()` as well).

```
values <- c(1, 5)
for (i in values) {
   p <- p + geom_segment(x=i, y=103, xend=i, yend=107)
}
```

Comment: What i posted will fix it. Don't use `aes()` in the `geom_segment()` in the loop.

Comment: That's what I thought. Do you know why adding a `print` statement or using `force` in the for loop doesn't *fix* the problem?

Comment: @csgillespie Because in this case you're still binding to the *variable* `i`, not the value. You can't force `aes` to resolve the name till it actually draws the plot. `force` is sometimes useful in situations like this, but with the non-standard evaluation of `aes` it won't help in this case.

Answer (score 20):

An alternative approach would be to avoid using a loop at all. You can pack your segment data up in a separate data.frame from your main data and use aes() to plot everything at once like so:

```
segment_data = data.frame(
    x = c(1, 5),
    xend = c(1, 5), 
    y = c(103, 103),
    yend = c(107, 107)
)

p = ggplot(df, ...) +
geom_segment(data = segment_data, aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend))
```

Comment: This does seem better. I can't even get the other answer to work!

Comment: @SkyWalker can you make this the answer?