# Using geom_segment() within a for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

My question is an exact duplicate of this one [1], but the provided answer isn't working on my system.

Question: How can I add geom_segment() layers within a for loop?  If I use aes, as the OP of the referenced question does, I also get only the last layer.  If, as the answerer suggests, I don't use aes, I don't get any segments at all.

Here is a minimal example:

```
  ga <- 2.39996322972865332
  p <- ggplot()
  p <- p + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1, 1))
  p <- p + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-1, 1))
  for (i in 0:2) {
    #     p <- p + geom_segment(x = -cos(i*ga), y = -sin(i*ga), xend = cos(i*ga), yend = sin(i*ga)) # No segments
    p <- p + geom_segment(aes(x = -cos(i*ga), y = -sin(i*ga), xend = cos(i*ga), yend = sin(i*ga))) # Only last segment
  }
  p
```

I'm using R version 3.1.2 and (apparently) ggplot2 version 1.0.0 on Ubuntu.

(Note: I get the same result if I use `repeat` or `while`.)

[1] [Enriching a ggplot2 plot with multiple geom_segment in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24617414/enriching-a-ggplot2-plot-with-multiple-geom-segment-in-a-loop)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skip the loop. Pass a vector to the i variable:

```
 p <- p + geom_segment(
                aes(x = -cos((0:2)*ga), y = -sin((0:2)*ga),
                    xend = cos((0:2)*ga), yend = sin((0:2)*ga))
                       )
```

Just a check to see that you *can* use a variable as well as a numeric constant:

```
 i <- 0:2
 p <- p + geom_segment(aes(x = -cos(i*ga), y = -sin(i*ga), 
                           xend = cos(i*ga), yend = sin(i*ga)) )
```

[image]

Comment: Ahhh brilliant!  I need to start vectorizing things in my head by default.  Thanks so much!

Comment: This the cleanest and useful solution. I found so many melting and data.frame "casting" and they were always suboptimal and often broken (e.g. if you use a different `data` for the main plotting).

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem, but could not avoid using a for loop. I solved it by

`adding inherit.aes = TRUE`

after the `aes()` statement within the `geom_segment()` statement.

Answer (score -1):

I just wanted to add one point to @BondedDust's answer.

If you try to put this into a function, something like this...

```
  draw.golden.angle <- function(n) {

  ga <- 2.39996322972865332
  p <- ggplot()
  p <- p + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1, 1))
  p <- p + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-1, 1))
  i <- 0:n
  p <- p + geom_segment(aes(x = -cos(i*ga), y = -sin(i*ga), xend = cos(i*ga), yend = sin(i*ga))) # Only last segment
  p

  }

  draw.golden.angle(7)
```

...you will get an error saying that the variable `i` isn't recognized.  You can fix this by assigning `i` to a *global* variable as follows:

```
i <<- 0:n
```

Comment: Assigning to a global variable is a very dangerous way to go about this.

Comment: Thanks for the warning, @Gregor--I will read up on global variables.  Is there another way you can think to do this?  If you'd like I can make it a separate question.

Comment: I can't think of a really easy way. The robust solution would be to add new data columns for each value of `i`, `melt`, and use `geom_segment` with a grouping variable, `aes(group = i)`. It's quite a bit more work, but that's the price we pay to have stable and reliable functions.

Comment: Also, `fortunes::fortune(236)`

Comment: And Circle 6 of [The R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) is about global assignment (and why you should never do it).

Comment: It is true that assignment to the enclosing frame is generally deprecated, but in this instance the "risk" would be external in a sense because the function would always succeed in the manner intended but any `i`-object in the enclosing frame would get clobbered. It's a bit different risk than one usually takes when using the super-assign. The term global-variable does not really apply here. The `<<-` function only makes an assignment to a named-object one level up. It's not guaranteed to be "global".